# Select BOTH table_rows AND column_name from information_schema

Tags: mysql, sql

I was asked to CREATE A PROCEDURE that lists TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS, COLUMN_NAME, and DATA_TYPE from a db.

Problem is, I can only select column_name using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and I can select table_rows using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table. I tried to join both but no success.

Also, I need to filter for VARCHAR columns with a CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 5
, but if I go "WHERE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 5" it will get not only varchar but also character data_types as well.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT c.table_name,  c.column_name, c.data_type, t.table_rows, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
   FROM information_schema.columns c
   JOIN information_schema.tables t ON c.table_name = t.table_name
   WHERE t.table_schema = 'SAMPLE' AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 5;
```

I think I got the proper join to work, but I'm still not sure how to get that "CHARACTER_MAXIMUN_LENGHT > 5" to only filter varchar data types...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude all data types except of `varchar` from your condition:

```
AND (CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 5 OR DATA_TYPE <> 'varchar')
```